# Marketing cloud - Multi org configuration and Tracking data

Tags: marketing-cloud

We are using Salesforce Marketing cloud connector and want to use Multi org configuration. So tracking data will get back to SalesCloud in case of any type of send(initiated in SalesCloud and Marketing cloud)?

Comment: You can find more details on your query here ...... http://sfmc-ninja.tech/SFMC_MCC_sync_email_tracking.html

Answer (score 1):

We have tried a POC with multi org configuration in one of the accounts and the tracking data seems to be updated properly. As like normal salesforce send, tracking data is updated as long as send in Marketing cloud is performed against lead id/contact id as subscriber key.

However there are a lot of other issues in the connectivity as the Multi org concept is still a beta version and i would personally recommend you to test all the scenarios before going ahead.

Comment: Can you share some of the issues you faced in connectivity? We have to upgrade to Multi-Org soon.