# Multi-org Connector to integrate Business units to Salesforce instances

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

we are going to upgrade soon to multi-org functionality in our account to integrate MC business units with different salesforce instances and I would like to know there will be any issues after Enabling Multi-org Connector

I have been looking Stack exchange questions for help but i didn't find solid answers 
[Marketing cloud - Multi org configuration and Tracking data](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/147862/marketing-cloud-multi-org-configuration-and-tracking-data)

[Marketing Cloud Connect multi-org configuration for Quality environment](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/155745/marketing-cloud-connect-multi-org-configuration-for-quality-environment)

[Difference between a Multi Org v/s Non-multi org setup for mapping multiple MC Business Units to 1 Sales Cloud Org](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/170111/difference-between-a-multi-org-v-s-non-multi-org-setup-for-mapping-multiple-mc-b)

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

I've implemented multi-org before and it is fairly straightforward. You need to follow the help documentation regarding Marketing Cloud Connector and you should be able to integrate a Salesforce Orgs to each Business Unit.

Once multi-org is enabled, you can't undo it. That should not be a concern if you are going to use more than 1 Salesforce Orgs. The only thing I can say is that there will be some challenges initially. I've had to work with Salesforce support to resolve issues like Tracking information not going to Sales Cloud, Queries unable to access Data extensions and with Journey Builder not having Salesforce activities visible.

I've also had issues after a Marketing Cloud release when Integration stops working and you have to login to Sales Cloud and enter the API user credentials in the Integration to make it work again.

Each set up is different and I believe you'll face a different set of challenges while you work on it. That being said, move forward with multi-org, coz that's the only option :) Good Luck

Comment: Is multi-org is different connector or after multi-org enable we can use same V5 Connectors for integrating both business units - correct me if i am wrong

Comment: You're correct, after you enable multi-org you will be using V5 connector for each business unit. The process will remain the same.

Comment: Hello @rajdeep  I read in the Documentation that custom fields and web tracking is not supported by multi-org, did you face any issues with this limitation, As we are using custom fields in our production so if we enable multi-org that functionality might break right??

Comment: I have faced an issue in my multi-org stuff, where when referencing synchronized data extension they have to be prefixed with "ent." even though they are in same BU. Working with Salesforce to confirm.

Comment: @KennethWagner  is there a way to know if the marketing cloud org is multi org connect enabled?

Answer (score 0):

The Multi-Org Configuration was introduced in version v5.494 of the Marketing Cloud Connector, so to enable this functionality you will need to ensure that you are upgraded to this version or higher.

Please note that once Multi-Org is turned on you cannot turn this feature off. Additionally, Multi-org is not compatible with the data stream functionality at this time.

For further information on Multi-org and the Connector releases please see:
http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/resources/release_notes/january_2016_release/#integrations